# qpython's special keys display funny characters

Tags: android, python, qpython

i have being finding it dificult to use special keys like up arrow, down arrow on qpython console. This keys work perfectly on qpython3 but not on qpython.
pls help.

Answer (score 0):

The features you are trying to access are not developed in QPython. It is not possible to access previously entered commands in QPython's console. Up and down arrows just display escape sequences. I asked the developer, as you can see on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950530/accessing-command-history-in-qpython-console-for-android).